# I want one icon needs to look disabled when other icon is selected and vice versa

Tags: angular

Below is my code. When SWIFT is selected then bank icon needs to look disabled. and vice versa.   and I want to implement css an html in below code only

```
<div class="toggle-container" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center" [ngClass]="{'bank-selected': defaultPaymentModeFormCtrl.value === constants.BANK}">
            <mat-icon class="swift-logo-payment" svgIcon="swift-logo" matTooltip="Swift"></mat-icon>
            <mat-slide-toggle
              color="primary"
              size="small" 
              [checked]="defaultPaymentModeFormCtrl.value === constants.BANK"
              (change)="paymentModeChange($event)">           
            </mat-slide-toggle>
            <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="iconDisabled"></button>
            <img src="../../../../assets/icons/bank-small.png" width="25px" height="30px" margin-top="25px" matTooltip="Bank"/>
          </div>
```

I have tried adding disabled, but it is throwing error like disabled does not existed on type component

Answer (score 0):

As example:

```
<mat-icon class="swift-logo-payment" svgIcon="swift-logo" matTooltip="Swift"
          [ngStyle]="{opacity: (defaultPaymentModeFormCtrl.value === constants.BANK) ? 0.65 : 1}, {cursor: 'default'}"></mat-icon>
```